# Every ordinal is the derived length of a group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Define inductively the [derived series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Derived_series) as follows:
$$G^{(0)}=G\\\\
G^{(\lambda)}=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}[G^{(\alpha)},G^{(\alpha)}]$$
Let $\text{sol}(G)=\{\min \alpha\in \text{Ord}:G^{(\alpha)}=G^{(\alpha+1)}\}$. Clearly $\text {sol}(G)\le |G|$.

It is claimed on wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#Hypoabelian)) that every ordinal number is the solving length of some group, and the reference provided for this is "Generalized nilpotent algebras and their associated groups" by Maltsev a paper which, unfortunately, is in russian.

To be more formal, let $\Omega:=\{\text{solv}(G): G\text{ is a group}\}\subset \text{Ord}$. How would you go about proving $\Omega=\text{Ord}$? Do you have a reference for it?

What I've done so far:

1. For every natural number $n$,  $\alpha+n\in \Omega\Rightarrow \alpha\in \Omega$ (just take $G^{(n)}$)
2. $\Omega$ is closed under $\sup$: given an increasing sequence $\lambda_i$ of elements in $\Omega$, denote by $G_i$ the associated groups and notice that $G:=\prod G_i$ satisfies $\text{sol}(G)=\sup \lambda_i$

Comment: What does the $[G, G]$ notation mean?

Comment: It means the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @MJD: Standard notation for the commutator subgroup. If $x,y\in G$, then $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $G$, then $[A,B]$ is the subgroup generated by all $[a,b]$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Comment: According to the [MathSciNet review of Mal'cev's paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&pg6=PC&s1=228172&s6=20&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=15&mx-pid=32644)  (subscription may be required), the examples for arbitrary ordinals are constructed using the group of quasiregular elements of "suitable algebras". An element $r$ of a ring $R$ is quasiregular if $1-r$ is a unit; and the quasiregular elements of a ring form a group under the circle operation $x\circ y = x+y+xy$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a field and let $U_n$ be the group of upper triangular $(n \times n)$-matrices with entries in $F$ and only $1$'s on the diagonal.

Then $U_n$ has derived length $d$, where $d$ is the integer such that $2^{d-1} < n \leq 2^d$. See for example Suzuki, Group Theory II, Chapter 4.

So this provides examples of groups with derived length $d$, for any $1 \leq d < \infty$.

I don't know how to give an example for infinite ordinals, and I have no access to the paper by Mal'cev. Perhaps the example of $U_n$ could be generalized to infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

EDIT: You might want to take a look at the following paper, which seems to answer your question: "B. Hartley, The order-types of central series. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 61 (1965), 303-319.".